# Rails: Change existing integer column to array data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, types, casting

How do I change an integer column (which already has values) to an integer array column? When I try to migrate this:

```
def change
  change_column :cards, :value, :integer, array: true, default: []
end
```

I get this error:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "value" cannot be cast automatically to type integer[]
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING value::integer[]"
```

So I tried this:

```
change_column :cards, :value, :integer, array: true, default: [], using: 'value::integer[]'
```

Then I get this error:

```
PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to integer[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging around for postgres casting functions & trying several things that didn't work, I found the answer.

`using: 'ARRAY[value]::INTEGER[]'`

The hint was close, but off by just enough to be confusing.