# PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: syntax error at or near "USING" LINE 1: SELECT 'integer[] USING ARRAY ... +rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am attempting to db:migrate:reset and encountered this error:

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USING"
LINE 1: SELECT 'integer[] USING ARRAY[pdf_page_number]::INTEGER...
              ^
CONTEXT:  invalid type name "integer[] USING ARRAY[pdf_page_number]::INTEGER[][]"
```

The migration file causing this error:

```
class ChangeCartItemsPageNumbersToArray < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    change_column :cart_items, :pdf_page_number, 'integer[] USING ARRAY[pdf_page_number]::INTEGER[]', array: true, null: false, default: []
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it:

```
change_column :cart_items, :pdf_page_number, :integer, using: 'ARRAY[pdf_page_number]::INTEGER[]', array: true, null: false, default: []
```

[This question/answer very helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725337/rails-change-existing-integer-column-to-array-data-type)